# Minecraft Command Block "You must specify which player you wish to perform this action on."

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a "Minecart Elevator" using command blocks. My main block has this command: `/tp @e[type=MinecartRideable, r=21] ~ ~+3.3 ~`. When I don't have the `, r=21` part, my command works, just without the radius. But, when I add the radius back in, I get this error:

```
You must specify which player you wish to perform this action on.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the player you want to perform that action on?

Comment: I want to perform the action on all the minecarts within a 21 block radius of the command block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in target selectors. It is assuming you are skipping to the next part of the command's syntax.

```
/tp @e[type=MinecartRideable,r=21] ~ ~+3.3 ~
```

Comment: Aww, you beat me to the answer :P

Answer (score -1):

Just use the nearest player command, `/tp @p[r=3] ~ ~+3.3 ~`

Comment: I was trying to teleport minecarts, not players. Please see the accepted answer for what I was looking for.